# What things have we to keep in mind before migrate from html4 web app to html5?

Tags: html, web-applications

I am a relatively new web apps programmer.

I have done differents web apps when HTML 5 were becoming (let's say) the new HTML standard.

So I want to know whether it is a good idea to migrate some of those apps to HTML 5.

By the way, I never have used HTML 5 in any web application.

What things do I have to keep in mind before do a migration or starts new web applications?

I mean: browsers, frameworks, javascript libraries, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way to enter in the world of HTML5 is using solid libs/frameworks that ensure your code [degrade gracefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault-tolerant_system) on older browsers.

One cool site to grab some tricks and hints is the [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com).

I'm a experienced [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/overview) developer (and I recommned it to Java developers), but I think that "the next big thing" may come from [Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/).

In the Javascript world, nothing beats the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) lib. Of course, in my opinion =)

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 is fully backwards compatible with previous versions of HTML. A few things are deprecated or obsolete, but browsers will still accept them until you can change them to something more up-to-date.

To start using HTML5, just replace your doctype with `<!DOCTYPE html>`